# How to get count of files Inside a subfolder- pnp-js?

Tags: sharepoint-online, subfolders, count, pnpjs

I can get the count of files in a root folder using this

```
pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Test").items.getAll().then((allItems) => {

    // how many did we get
    console.log(allItems.length);

});
```

But, how do I get the count of Items inside a Sub Folder?

For Instance

Suppose the Folder Test, contained the following sub-folders-

```
Test
   -Test-1
          -Test-1-1
           -Test-1-2
   -Test-2
   -Test-3
```

Test contains 3 folders-(Test-1, Test-2 and Test-3)

Test-1 contains two folders (Test-1-1 and Test-1-2)

How do I get the count of Test-1-1 using the above code?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by using this logic

```
   pnp.sp.web.folders.getByName('Test').folders.getByName("Test-1").folders.getByName("Test-1-1").files.get().then((allItems) => {

            // how many did we get
            console.log(allItems.length);


        });
```